# nullable object must have a value on a foreach

Tags: c#

I have the following code that is giving me an error on my variable y++, "Nullable object must have a value'..

```
 @{
    int year = Model.Program.Select(p => p.Year.GetValueDefault()).Distinct();
    int yearList = year.ToList();

    foreach(var p in Model.Programs)
    {
        /* Exception occurs on next line */
        for(int y = p.StartYear.Value; y < p.Year.Value; y++)
        {
         yearList.Add(y);
        }
    }
   year = yearList.Distinct().OrderByDescending(y => y);
  }
```

Any tips?

Comment: what is the type of `StartYear`?

Comment: p.StartYear is the culprit...not y.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get `.Value` of the property that is `null`. Try to apply `Where` in your foreach:

```
foreach(var p in Model.Programs.Where(g => g.StartYear.HasValue && g.Year.HasValue))
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nullable that doesn't have a value, and you try to ask it for it's value, you get this exception:

```
int? myNullable = null;
Console.Write("value is "+myNullable.Value); //"nullable must have value" exception thrown
```

Make sure your `p.StartYear` nullable has a value, or check for `p.HasValue` and only run your loop if it's true

Answer (score 0):

I Coud see more than 1 problem:

1 - The variable "year" must be a List, and not a simple Int. You can replace the declaration "int year = " to "var year = ";

2 - In sintax "int yearList = year.ToList();" the variable yearList must be a List, and not a simple Int. You can replace the declaration "int yearList = year.ToList();" to "var yearList = year.ToList();"

3 - Also, i Think the variable p.StartYear.Value is'nt an Int, is a null, and it's the reazon of your message error.

I belive the datatype of "p.StartYear.Value" isnt int.